# Mysql same query running different

Tags: mysql

I'm updating a table containing 175.901 rows, when I run this query:

`UPDATE wm_rendiconti_orchard SET user_id = NULL WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL`

I get "72 rows affected. no errors", if I run it again I get "221 rows affected" then again with "23 rows affected"... I don't get it.

How is this possible?!

This is a video where you can see what I mean: [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d6hflbptcuv73vd/OKFhTk0ukl)

And this is how the table is constructed:

```
CREATE TABLE `wm_rendiconti_orchard` (
    `DMS` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Territory` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPC` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Label` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Artist` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `ISRC_ISBN` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '',
    `Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Trans_Type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Label_Share_Net_Receipts` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Trimestre_month` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `Trimestre_year` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
    `eur` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `eur_80` double DEFAULT NULL,
    `rendi_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`rendi_id`),
    KEY `rendi_id` (`rendi_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=175902 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: And what does `SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM this_table` show? What if you run that query again after some period?

Comment: New data is probably getting inserted into the table (with a user_id) between your UPDATEs.

Comment: @Jack Well, that would be too obvious, I'm eager to discover more... esoteric reasons. )

Comment: @raina77ow I find it is usually best to rule out the obvious things first ;-)

Comment: Ok, it's kind of weird but the only reason I could think of is that I had a query that I started AND STOPPED (closed the browser page AND browser itself) like 20 minutes BEFORE, and even if the browser was closed the query was still running... This all in local (with MAMP). I found out by rebooting the system and that problem stoped showing. Is this possible? How?

Comment: @Mr.Web Very possible. If you were just using phpMyAdmin to interact with MySQL server then it's possible it because unresponsive under load so it never got the signal to kill the query and just happily continued to run. MySQL doesn't know you were interacting with it via a browser so it doesn't care that it was shut. If you have an issue like this again you should use the mysql cli and try running     `show processlist;` to see what's actually running.